# Can't run .run Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I'm trying to install a program from a .run file in Ubuntu 18.04.

I tried using:
`sudo chmod +x quartus.run` and `sudo ./quartus.run`

But nothing happens and nothing shows in the terminal. When I try double click the icon, I get a popup saying:

```
     Could not display "quartus.run"
     There is no application installed for "executable" files.
```

After allowing executing file as program in the permissions, double clicking does nothing.

I have only recently installed ubuntu and installed with "minimal setup", am i missing something?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! What are the contents of the file? Where did you get it? Could you post a link to it and to the guide you are following?

Comment: @Melebius Thanks! I'm trying to install Quartus II for University but the board i'm using is only compatible with version 13sp1. Here is the [link](https://fpgasoftware.intel.com/13.0sp1/?edition=web&download_manager=dlm3&platform=linux)

I'm not following a guide, i just googled to find the right commands but it does not seem to be working for me.

Comment: did you follow the install instruction? It has instructions that this does not work using "dash" and what to do prior to installing. Next: where did you get that file? The downloads I see all download a script ending in ".sh".

Comment: https://fpgawiki.intel.com/wiki/Quartus_for_Linux seems to be rather throrough

Comment: @Rinzwind I did not follow the installation/quick start guide because it did not say anything about the .run file i downloaded.  I got it from the individuals files tab. Perhaps I should just download the combined file.

Comment: @Rinzwind Ah thankyou, i'm downloading the .tar as we speak!

Comment: Please run `file ./quartus.run` and `ldd ./quartus.run` and include the outputs in your question.  Thanks!